# React js +Redux server side pagination, filtering and searching

Tags: reactjs, datatables, redux

I searched a lot but found no solution as i need server side pagination.Currently im using jquery datatables with react on client side but since now records have increased upto 3k. So now the requirement would oviously be a server side pagination. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated for any 3rd party library to implement this or can that be done with a custom component only. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: No, but i created custom bootstrap table and custom filters, react-paginate for pagination. On back-end side managed functionality in Node.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer this question, but i hope it might help others you can use table-boy npm package for server side sorting pagination and fetching.No jquery!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/table-boy